# Passing pointer to memory-mapped interface

Tags: c

I have a global pointer to a memory mapped device initialised as follows:

```
volatile char *base_address = (char *) 0xa0000000;
```

During program execution I have a switch statement, and depending on the input the
base_address pointer has to be adjusted as you can see below:

```
    switch (input) {
        case 'S': 
        base_address = (char *) 0xa0001000;
        InitDevice();
    break;
        case 'A': 
        base_address = (char *) 0xa0001000;
        InitDevice();
            break
```

TBH, this looks like a dirty hack to me and it would be probably nicer to pass the base_address to the function `InitDevice((char *) 0xa0001000)`. Would the latter be the proper way to do that or are there better approaches?

Many thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5):

Yep, explicitly passing a required parameter to a function is always better than passing it via a global variable.

In an embedded environment, you might have to consider that calling a function with a parameter might require the parameter to be pushed onto the stack and popped otherwise (unless the compiler optimizes and passes it in a register). But I wouldn't optimize based on this unless I have established (through measuring) that the speed gain is actually worth polluting the code.
(And since your example is switching over input, which is usually coming at glacial speed compared to stack operations, this shouldn't be a problem here anyway.)

However, as Lars said in a comment, it would probably be better if those literal addresses were replaced by symbolic constants:

```
volatile char* const A_base_address = (char *) 0xa0001000;
volatile char* const S_base_address = (char *) 0xa0001000;

switch (input) {
case 'S': 
    InitDevice(S_base_address);
    break;
case 'A': 
    InitDevice(A_base_address);
    break;
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a 'dirty hack', though, just sloppy programming. Likewise with the fact that the base address is given as literal constant. But I'm curious if there are calls to InitDevice() without a change to the base address.

Comment: @Lars: I hadn't called it a "dirty hack". Thanks for the idea of using symbolic constants instead of literals. I have incorporated that.

Comment: Those aren't symbolic constants. They're global variables, and they reduce efficiency with no benefit. Instead create them with `#define` and they're free: `#define A_base_address ((char *)0xa0001000)`. By the way, like this you can even make mmio registers look/work like plain variables: `#define MYREG (*(char *)0x12345678)` etc.

Comment: @R..: I know this is a C question, and I'm on shaky ground when it comes to C, but I'm sure a C++ compiler would optimize those globals away (unless their address is taken). And besides the wasted bytes for two variables, why would pushing a global const value onto the stack reduce efficiency compared to pushing a literal value?

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. I know of no C compiler that will make this optimization, unless perhaps you compile the whole program as one unit. And the waste I'm talking about is (x86 here but translate to whatever) `movl $A_base_address, %eax ; pushl (%eax)` versus `pushl $0xa0001000`. There's also the issue that the former requires a relocation, possibly meaning non-sharable memory or addressing through the GOT in PIC code. And since writing MMIO registers sounds like embedded system code, you really don't want any of these inefficiencies there!

Comment: @sbi: even C++ wouldn't be able to optimize this away, since you didn't declare the pointer `const`.

Comment: @Jens: That's true. I've fixed that now.

Comment: @R.. I guess that the additional load instruction might be a problem sometimes in embedded environments.